# Difference in execution flow of XML configuration vs Annotation configuration of Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring

The following is the code performing the same task but with different configurations in Spring framework.

**A.java**

```
package com.kyc.spring;    
public class A {
    private int a;
    private String msg;
    static{
        System.out.println("A-S.B");
    }
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A-D.C");
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        System.out.println("A-setA()");
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        System.out.println("A-setMsg()");
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return ""+a+"\t"+msg;
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
package com.kyc.spring;
public class B {
    private int b;
    private String msg;
    static{
        System.out.println("B-S.B");
    }
    public B() {
        System.out.println("B-D.C");
    }
    public B(int b, String msg) {
        System.out.println("B-2arg");
        this.b = b;
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return ""+b+"\t"+msg;
    }
}
```

**Hello.java**

```
package com.kyc.spring;
public class Hello {
    private A aobj;
    private B bobj;
    static{
        System.out.println("Hello-S.B");
    }
    public Hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello-D.C");
    }
    public void setAobj(A aobj) {
        System.out.println("Hello-setAobj()");
        this.aobj = aobj;
    }
    public void setBobj(B bobj) {
        System.out.println("Hello-setBobj()");
        this.bobj = bobj;
    }
    public Hello(A aobj, B bobj) {
        System.out.println("Hello-2arg");
        this.aobj = aobj;
        this.bobj = bobj;
    }
    public void show() {
        System.out.println(aobj);
        System.out.println(bobj);
    }
}
```

## using XML-Configuration:

**kyc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="aobj" class="com.kyc.spring.A" >
        <property name="a" value="10" />
        <property name="msg" value="I am A" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bo" class="com.kyc.spring.B" >
        <constructor-arg value="20" />
        <constructor-arg value="I am B" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="hello" class="com.kyc.spring.Hello" autowire="byName" />
</beans>
```

**Test1.java**

```
package com.kyc.spring;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("kyc.xml");
        System.out.println("Spring Container STARTS");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        Hello hello = (Hello)ctx.getBean("hello");
        hello.show();
    }
}
```

## using Annotation-Configuration:

**Kyc.class**

```
package com.kyc.spring;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Kyc {
    @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
    public Hello hello(){
        return new Hello();
    }
    @Bean
    public A aobj(){
        A aobj = new A();
        aobj.setA(10);
        aobj.setMsg("I am A");
        return aobj;
    }
    @Bean
    public B bo(){
        return new B(20, "I am B");
    }
}
```

**Test2.java**

```
package com.kyc.spring;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Kyc.class);
        System.out.println("Spring Container STARTS");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        Hello hello = (Hello) ctx.getBean("hello");
        hello.show();               
    }
}
```

## Now let us take a look at the output of the both Test1 and Test2..

```
##for Test1:##
---------------
A-S.B
A-D.C
A-setA()
A-setMsg()
B-S.B
B-2arg
Hello-S.B
Hello-D.C
Hello-setAobj()
Spring Container STARTS.
--------------------------
10           I am A
null

##for Test2:##
--------------
Hello-S.B
Hello-D.C
A-S.B
A-D.C
A-setA()
A-setMsg()
B-S.B
B-2-arg
Spring Container STARTS.
--------------------------
10           I am A
null
```

## Why is that the output of (or the Execution flow) of Test1.java is not identical to Test2.java?

Answer (score 2):

To get comparable results you should declare your beans in both the kyc.xml and the Kyc.java with the same ordering.

After changing kyc.xml so that the beans are ordered in the same way as in Kyc.java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="hello" class="com.kyc.spring.Hello" autowire="byName" />

    <bean id="aobj" class="com.kyc.spring.A" >
        <property name="a" value="10" />
        <property name="msg" value="I am A" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bo" class="com.kyc.spring.B" >
        <constructor-arg value="20" />
        <constructor-arg value="I am B" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

the output for test1 is

```
Hello-S.B
Hello-D.C
A-S.B
A-D.C
A-setA()
A-setMsg()
Hello-setAobj()
B-S.B
B-2arg
Spring Container STARTS
--------------------------
10  I am A
null
```